# Easy way to track website user activity

Tags: asp.net

We want to track all visitor activities for logged users so we can get better insight into visitor behavior and gather more data for each individual user.

What options are available for something like this that does not require us to add code to every single website page? Are there some existing libraries for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple different options you can try:

1. If your website uses one or more master pages you can try adding code only to master pages.
2. Create custom http module you will later integrate into IIS. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article for more details